# Sync Windows 10 / Outlook 365 calendar to GMail ... continuously?

Tags: sync, google-calendar, microsoft-outlook-365

I recently started a new job, and wish to have my work and private calendars shown side-by-side on both my workstation and my private GMail account (which I can then see on my Android phone). I've had this working fine over a decade ago. FWIW, both of these are intended to be read-only one-way connections, but continuously updated rather than merely one-time snapshots.

After a few attempts I did get the GMail-to-Outlook part working, and I can also enter the ICS info from my work Outlook calendar into my GMail calendar ... but it is only synced once. Subsequent updates never get synced over to be visible from GMail. I fail to see how that is ever useful.

All guides that I've been able to find refer to older versions of Windows and/or Outlook, and aren't really clear on whether they provide *continuously updated* synchronisation.

Surely, someone has gotten this to work?

Comment: [It](https://insider.office.com/en-us/blog/starting-to-support-third-party-accounts-in-new-outlook-for-windows-preview) should be possible, but the Android portion of your question, isn’t within scope

Comment: The Android part is trivially relevant; I've rephrased to focus on my GMail account.

Comment: Are you able to install the current Insider Preview build for Outlook for Windows on the machine?

Comment: The what for what now? I think not, this is a business workstation and I don't think I'm supposed to install pre-release software on it. Why, what can it do that official Office 365 cannot?

Comment: Microsoft is adding the feature to support Google Mail, and other email providers, historically in my experience Outlook support for Google Mail has always been extremely hit and miss.  Hence the reason they are adding it to Outlook for Windows.  There use to be an add-on that made it less horrible, it only supported Google written by Google, and was discontinued by Google 5+ years ago.